# Is it possible to exclude non-business days from a dyGraph of an xts object in R?

Tags: r, r-dygraphs

I have seen the use of `scale_x_bd` for `ggplot2` in the `bdscale` package, but I'm not sure how to achieve the same thing in a `dygraph` (from the `dygraphs` package) or whether it is even possible by hacking the corresponding `xts` object?

Comment: Use tidyquant to get a stock time series.  It will only have values for when the markets are open.  Join that with the dates in your time series.

Comment: @HarlanNelson I already don’t have any values on weekends but the digraph just creates a long flat line connecting across weekends

Comment: I see the problem.